# Jhipster or Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I have a question related with pagination with native query. I need to retrieve 
data between two dates and I don't want to lose pagination.  How to handle it? (And we are using Local Date) . Thanx

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resolve it by using @Query annotation. Besides, I used Pageable object. If u fill the pageable object properly, u can manage it readily. Furthermore, sometimes, u can need to use @Param annotation. Look at the last sample in 5.3.4 Using Query and 5.3.6. Using named parameters.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: Don't post link without outputing the needed content, those link can die meaning your "answer" would become invalid. See [answer]